# What's wrong with this reference code?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to compile a latex document and I am getting a weird error from the bbl file.
Specifically a certain reference snippet gives the compiler an error:

```
@inproceedings{FEPPS04,
  author    = {Paola Flocchini and
               Antonio Mesa Enriques and
               Linda Pagli and
               Giuseppe Prencipe and
               Nicola Santoro},
  title     = {Efficient Protocols for Computing the Optimal Swap Edges of a                    Shortest Path Tree},
  booktitle = {Exploring New Frontiers of Theoretical Informatics, {IFIP} 18th World
               Computer Congress, {TC1} 3rd International Conference on Theoretical
               Computer Science (TCS2004), 22-27 August 2004, Toulouse, France},
  pages     = {153--166},
  year      = {2004},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-4020-8141-3_14},
  doi       = {10.1007/1-4020-8141-3_14},
  timestamp = {Wed, 16 Jul 2014 12:43:29 +0200},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/ifipTCS/FlocchiniEPPS04},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

Any idea of what might be the problem? I have several references in the bbl but none other causes any problems during compilation.
If nothing else works I will replace this reference by another but I was wondering of what might be the problem with it, thus my question here.

Comment: Welcome. I get no error if I use that item in a standard document using `biblatex`. Can you please mention the “weird error” you get?

Comment: " I am getting a weird error from the bbl file" isn't anything anyone can debug, what error, from what program, from biber or bibtex writing the bbl, from latex reading it? Possibly your bib style is not handling `_` correctly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using overleaf. The error is as follows: <inserted text> 
                $
l.171 ...tp://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-4020-8141-3_14}
                                                  
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Comment: it would be better to use a code block in the question to show the message so line ends kept. so as I guessed `_` is being seen as a math subscript. But as you have shown no code we can not know why or what you should change

Comment: ideally you would fix the bibliography style doi handling but  `\_` or `\string_` might work, hard to say with no example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just removed the link

Comment: What happens if you load the `xurl` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the URL strings are fairly long, and because both the `url` field and the `doi` field contain an `_` (underscore) character, I suggest you load the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other document class
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@inproceedings{FEPPS04,
  author    = {Paola Flocchini and Antonio Mesa Enriques and Linda Pagli and Giuseppe Prencipe and Nicola Santoro},
  title     = {Efficient Protocols for Computing the Optimal Swap Edges of a Shortest Path Tree},
  booktitle = {Exploring New Frontiers of Theoretical Informatics, {IFIP} 18th World Computer Congress, {TC1} 3rd International Conference on Theoretical Computer Science (TCS2004), 22--27 August 2004, Toulouse, France},
  pages     = {153--166},
  year      = {2004},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/1-4020-8141-3_14},
  doi       = {10.1007/1-4020-8141-3_14},
  timestamp = {Wed, 16 Jul 2014 12:43:29 +0200},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/ifipTCS/FlocchiniEPPS04},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{FEPPS04}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```